# git pull and lose any local changes

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a CI system which pulls code from Github for testing.  It starts out with a clone of the repo and then, when a new commit appears, it is given the hash of the commit and does:

`git pull --no-rebase origin <hash>`

`git -c advice.detachedHead=false checkout --no-progress <hash>`

No changes are ever made to the code, nothing is ever pushed, only pulled.

However, every so often `git pull` fails with a merge conflict:

`Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files. hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>' hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit. fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.`

When this happens I've tried doing `git reset --hard` as a recovery mechanism and doing the `pull` once more but that does not help, the same merge conflict prevents the `pull` from working and I'm stuck.

Can anyone tell me the bit of git magic that I'm missing which will always make every `pull` succeed, vaping the [non existent] local changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to do tests on said revision, why do you pull into a local branch (and face this kind of messes that happen when you try to merge stuff)? Try fetching and checking out instead:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout <hash>
```

That should do. No more need to deal with conflicts or what-not. You should even consider try a `git clean -f` in the process if possible so that files that were generated as part of the (previous) build process disappear as well.

Comment: An excellent point: I think it was originally simply because `git pull` happened to bring all branches down and I'd not realised there was a `git fetch --all`. You're absolutely right that I have no need of a local branch, I will try simple `fetch` and `checkout`.

Comment: @Rob: for beginners: never use `--all` with `git fetch`. For more advanced users: consider using `--all` instead of `for remote in $(git remote); do git fetch $remote; done`.

Comment: @torek: OK now I'm going to have to ask: why never use `--all` with `git fetch`?

Comment: @Rob: because it means *all remotes*. People expect it to mean *all branches* and feeding that expectation just [leads them down the garden path](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lead+down+the+garden+path).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification: so is there an equivalent of `--allbranches`?

Comment: worth noting : `git checkout <hash>; git restore -s <hash> --worktree -- .` should also run the "clean" part

Comment: @Rob there is no need for `--allbranches`. `git fetch` will sync all remote references of a remote... _unless_ you also tell it specifically what you want from a remote: `git fetch some-remote some-branch`.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed not clear to me before.